# Can Someone Point Me To Days Of the Month Source Code?

Tags: c, ios, calendar

I am building and iOS app that requires a minimal calendar. Just days of the month really. Has anyone come across bare bones source code - c-code is fine - that when given a month and year can generate the correct days of the month?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Do you need days of the week?

Comment: Also, I don't do iOS, but I'd be shocked if there wasn't functionality built-in to iOS that did this for you.

Comment: Is this `c` or `objective-c`.  If the latter, then this should be retagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the IOS Date and Time Programming guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW1

They have the following example showing how to get the day of the week from an NSDate:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                     initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
                [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
NSInteger day = [weekdayComponents day];
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Comment: Whoa. I'll have to check this out. Cool. Thanks jjwchoy.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://www.codecogs.com/code/units/date/daysinmonth.php with google. I don't know if you can do something with it. The sad thing is that you have to register on the site to download the complete source...